# How do I get input in an option in discordpy?

Tags: python, discord, slash

I am working on this command for a bot and I am not sure how I would get the text after an option, so like:
`/userinfo name: Hatsune Miku`
and prints out `hatsune miku` in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using discord-interactions you can do:

In cogs

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash import cog_ext, SlashContext
from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_option

class Slash(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @cog_ext.cog_slash(name='userinfo', description="get user info", options=[create_option(name="name", description="Name", option_type=3, required=True)])
    async def _userinfo(self, ctx, name):
        await ctx.send(name)
```

in main.py

```
from discord_slash import SlashCommand

client = commands.Bot(...)
slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands=True)
```

Comment: I don't use cogs but someone else has helped me figure it out in Discord, although thank you for the answer. Really appreciated.